# Appending txt files, how to repeat for many files

Tags: python, append, arcmap

I am importing ascii gridded files (.txt) into ArcMap to create a raster image. I am attempting to do as much as possible using Python code....but haven't got too far yet!

I am currently starting the process by appending the .hdr files to the .txt files. First I am manually converting the hdr file to txt, so I can append two txt files. (I would appreciate it if someone could suggest a quicker way to do this please. Can you append hdr to txt?).

I am then appending the two txt files individually using the following script:

filenames = ['hdr.txt', 'yyyymmout.txt']
with open("yyyymm_hdr", 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)

This script is working fine for the individual files, but I would like to attempt to do all the files within the script. I have a file for each month from 1900-2010....e.g. 1200+...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

> First I am manually converting the hdr file to txt, so I can append two txt files.

You want to attach the contents of `hdr.txt` before each file? You don't need to append them for this, you can do it on the fly.

If `hdr.txt` is pretty small, just read the whole thing into memory, and write that to each output file before copying from the input file.

---

> This script is working fine for the individual files, but I would like to attempt to do all the files within the script. I have a file for each month from 1900-2010....e.g. 1200+...

So you just need to write some code that can generate the year-month filenames, right?

```
('{}{}out.txt'.format(y, m) for y in range(1900, 2011) for m in range(1, 13))
```

Or, if you don't understand compressions:

```
for y in range(1900, 2011):
    for m in range(1, 13):
        fname = '{}{}out.txt'.format(y, m)
        with open(fname) as infile:
            # etc.
```

---

Also, if you just want to copy an entire file to another file, and the files aren't too large to fit in memory, it's a lot simpler to just `read()` one file and `write()` to the other.

---

So, putting it together, I think what you want is:

```
with open('hdr.txt') as f:
    hdr = f.read()

for y in range(1900, 2011):
    for m in range(1, 13):
        infname = '{}{}in.txt'.format(y, m)
        outfname = '{}{}out.txt'.format(y, m)
        with open(infname) as infile, open(outfname, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(hdr)
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```